# Using perform with a WITH clause in case of multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use PERFORM with a WITH query that returns multiple rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS void AS $$

BEGIN

PERFORM (
WITH selection AS (
    SELECT id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS r,
    first_value(id) OVER w AS first_value,
    nth_value(id, 5) OVER w AS last_value
    FROM mytable
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY v.ability_id ORDER BY unit_id ASC)
)
create_question(id, 1, 1, 1) 
FROM selection
WHERE ability_id IN (
    SELECT ability_id
    FROM selection
    WHERE last_value > 0.5
    ORDER BY first_value DESC
)
AND selection.r <= 5
);

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and I get the error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The postgres doc says it can't be done:

> For WITH queries, use PERFORM and then place the query in parentheses. (In this case, the query can only return one row.)

What could be done to solve this problem, apart from writing the With query (called selection here) twice ?

Comment: I don't see `ability_id` being selected in your CTE.

Comment: Yes, I simplified my query to give the flavour of what I was trying to achieve. The actual one has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark:** Your query is missing a `SELECT` right before `create_question(id, 1, 1, 1)`.

The trick is to modify the query so that it returns a single row.

You can do that by using an aggregate function, e.g. write:

```
SELECT
   count(create_question(id, 1, 1, 1))
FROM selection
...
```

Then the query only returns a single row and can be used as a subquery in the `PERFORM` statement.